# Request to reopen question 329904

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I would like to request to reopen: [What are threads, and what do they do in the processor?](https://superuser.com/q/329904/20433)

This question is perfect for SuperUser SE. Computer hardware question that isn't related to buying recommendations can be asked here per [SuperUser FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq).

Here is a quote from: [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](https://superuser.com/faq#dontask)

> However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

Isn't that what the user is asking? He is asking others to explain what CPU threads are its purpose.

Comment: The FAQ says "Probably OK" :) — Well, remind you that what you see is not what they were asking from the beginning on. Simon edited it and made it more general, which I think can now be answered.

Comment: @slhck I knew someone was going to bring that up. Yeah, I did see it. I hope it doesn't become the centering point of the discussion. I didn't look the edited history; probably should have. However, ask you pointed out, it now can be answered.

Answer (score 5):

I saw this question was aimed to be closed, and edited in to be a bit more general, but focusing on what threads were in relation to the processor. It seems to be closed, but I support it being re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the question has since been reopened by community vote.